# Xcode and SCM Commit Error

Tags: svn, xcode, ipad, version-control, commit

I set up SCM (SVN) for my ipad project. checkout etc. worked good, but when i want to commit changes i get following error:

> Error: 125001 (Bogus filename) Description: Couldn't determine absolute path of '.'

any advice?

thanks + regards

Answer (score 1):

I realise you probably don't have this problem anymore, but I just came across this myself and thought I'd document my findings.

I discovered that by doing a commit in XCode (after just having setup my project in svn) I got that same error. But when I went to the Terminal and did a commit int he command line, all was well. Next commit in XCode also proved to have the same problems, even after doing an `svn cleanup` via command line. All in all, I restarted XCode and voila, it worked happy again.